# C# saving the content of the richtextbox to an file

Tags: c#

I want to save the Text of an richtextbox with a filehelper to an txt file, so i can load back in the richtextbox on the start of my programm.

So if I print the content to a string and then i want to convert it to a bytearray. After this i want to print the bytearray into my txt file.
And the textfile i want to load during the start of my programm into the richtextbox.

My filehelper:

```
namespace Kontomanager_0._3
{
  public class filehelper
  {

    public filehelper(string myPath)
    {
        myPath = MyPath;
    }

    private string MyPath { get; }

    public byte[] ReadByteString()
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(MyPath);
    }

    public void WriteAllBytes(byte[] arrayToWrite)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(MyPath, arrayToWrite);
    }

    internal static byte[] ReadAllBytesStatic(string myPath)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(myPath);
    }


  }
}
```

My Windows form code:

```
namespace Kontomanager_0._3
{
  //private filehelper FileHelper { get; set; }
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    filehelper file = new filehelper("Aktivitaeten.txt");

    //Gutschriftvariablen
    string gBetrag;
    string gAbsender;
    string gDatum;

    //Abbuchungvariablen
    string aBetrag;
    string aEmpfaenger;
    string aDatum;

    // Transaktionenzähler variablen
    int counter;
    string lbcounter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGutschrift_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gutschrift();
    }

    private void btnAbbuchung_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Abbuchung();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Speichern();
    }

    private void btnBeenden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }


    void Gutschrift()
    {
        Zähler();
        gBetrag = this.tbgBetrag.Text;
        gAbsender = this.tbgAbsender.Text;
        gDatum = this.tbgDatum.Text;

        this.tbLog.Text += "(" + lbcounter + ")" + "[" + gDatum + "] " + gBetrag + "€ Erhalten von" + gAbsender + "\n";
    }

    void Abbuchung()
    {
        Zähler();
        aBetrag = this.tbaBetrag.Text;
        aEmpfaenger = this.tbaEmpfaenger.Text;
        aDatum = this.tbaDatum.Text;

        this.tbLog.Text += "(" + lbcounter + ")" + "[" + aDatum + "] " + aBetrag + "€ Gesendet an: " + aEmpfaenger + "\n";
    }

    void Zähler()
    {
        counter += 1;

        lbcounter = counter.ToString();

        lbTransaktionen.Text = "Transaktionen: " + lbcounter;
    }

    void Speichern()
    {
        string text;
        text = this.tbLog.Text;
        string path = "Aktivitaeten.txt";

            DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Datei hier abspeichern" + path, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if(Result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                // File überschreiben und speichern
                byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, array);

            }
            else if (Result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                // 
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe any sort of problem you're having...

Comment: what's your question exactly? Does this code not do what you want?

Comment: just showing off that you already have the code you are asking for? cool.

Comment: How can i print the content of the richtextbox in the same format throw my filehelper into an .txt file @stuartd

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom but it doesn´t work

Comment: @knuVe can you post an example of your desired result and your actual result? so we can compare and answer accordingly?

Comment: My actual result is nothing and my desired result is an .txt file in my projectfolder with the following format: (number)[Date]Amount of Money from name

Comment: Have you tried opening the result file in a notepad++ instead of the default text editor? ;)

Comment: _my desired result is an .txt file in my projectfolder_ - this code will create a file in the `bin\Debug` folder as you're not specifying a path, so it will be created in the current directory of the exe file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code is totally wrong

```
public filehelper(string myPath)
{
    myPath = MyPath;
}

private string MyPath { get; }
```

I suppose you wanted to write

```
public filehelper(string myPath)
{
    MyPath = myPath;
}

private string MyPath { get; set;}
```

Becouse the code you used resulted in having empty value of MyPath, variable you used to hold name of file you wanted to read and write into. Apart from that, your code seems to be working for me.

Comment: Nice spot. `File.WriteAllBytes` [will throw an `ArgumentException` if the path passed to it is null though](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), and OP doesn't seem to be actually using  the FileHelper at all, perhaps because of that, and is calling `File.WriteAllBytes(path, array);` instead.

Comment: Ups, didn´t notice that. Well if he used filehelper, it should work tbh.

Comment: so now it prints the Text but only in one line. But i want it to be every sentence in a new line

Comment: You will have to use this code becouse in richTextBox lines are separated by "\n" but files in windows use \r\n. 
`byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text.Replace("\n",Environment.NewLine));
`

Comment: @pajamac IT WORKS THANKS

Comment: Glad to hear that :)